# Keras 2 adding layer input_shape error

Tags: python, keras

I'm doing a neural network with `keras` and `python`, but when I try to add input layer with Dense function it gives back an error:

> File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\internal\containers.py", line 204, in **getitem**
>       return self._values[key]
>
> TypeError: descriptor '_values' for 'BaseContainer' objects doesn't apply to 'RepeatedCompositeFieldContainer' object

CODE:

```
classifier.add(Dense(units= 6, input_shape = (11,), activation = 'relu', kernel_initializer = 'uniform'))
```

Can you help me with that?

Comment: Can you provide the full code, and indicate where the error happens?

Comment: Well i think it doesn't matter know, i reinstalled keras and the same line works perfecty. I don't know what happend. Anyway thanks @rvinas :)